# Android OneDrive SDK show disk capacity

Tags: android, onedrive

I'm using [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android) in my Android application.

I need to show available storage capacity to the user.

I've searched for long time, but without any result. Is there any way to realize this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Peter from the OneDrive Team.  The storage usage information is available on a [Drive](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/default.htm) under the Quota facet, which has fields like remaining which you could use to show space information.

Here is a quick example with the OneDrive SDK for Android that will show a toast of the drive id and the space remaining.

```
oneDriveClient
   .getDrive()
   .buildRequest()
   .get(new ICallback<Drive>() {
      @Override
      public void success(final Drive drive) {
         final String msg = "Found Drive " + drive.id + ", with " drive.quota.remaining + " bytes available";
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   });
```